# Unity3d Connection functions order (different scenes)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I ve got Menu scene and Level1 scene. The Level1 scene has few rpc functions and OnConnectedToServer function which spawn player object. The menu scene has connect button with Network.Connect script and also OnConnectedToServer function that loads Level1 scene. Is there a way that OnConnectedToServer from Menu scene will execute before OnConnectedToServer from Level1 scene and before rpc functions from Level1

[link to Unity Network Class doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Network.html)